# Narrowing of generic types for mapping functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd expect recent versions of TS (see for example [#43183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43183)) to make this pattern possible without unsafe casting. Any ideas? ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220429#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDMYCWA7AczgF44BvAKDmrjwFcBbAI2CgC5bGWoBuKmgM4wo%20AhyEjCfAL58KAMzp4AxjBwQ8cAsBgAeANJxQMYHgAmAuAGtgiCPPRZchAHwAKG4g76AlB0zYogDa%20gC65PzUAgDuODDKABZwHrY%20ETQZcMoYAqgARPTMrHlskZkZAPQVcACiAEp1APJ1HAAqyKgA5IXcnXA4lngQ8DkCOAR4GEwANqgwEAgdcJ0BzgQhoZ1l5dRQOnRQmgAsAEw8cFVwAIJmZqJweTmOgYQbeXDR0FYCADRwTHR4ABJTpmIzgYCqOCtADKCAW8nGB1QcTgEEB-0Q-RguWm8m2NGyuQeElEJQJ5Uu9SaLWhS06pMIfQGtGGcFG40mMzmCyQKGWq2CYS2O0yexgB00eQSwGm0wgeT4orMwHkGDo0xgpVFGRgCSgEGiDwAcsAAG6sOB7DCJYBmP4A%20DDGVQWLE2H9QZshJOLzLABiSlU6k00xt3yM5nu4slcCEGBMDFMME6irK0goGYoyg0QjgdAEGG0AHUvgIrgIahDVHaSORaBxtDA3AUuMUfH8BI2dC3GQQ8mlZBQgA))

```js
export type Mapping = {
    number: number;
    string: string;
};

function get<K extends keyof Mapping>(key: K): Mapping[K] {
    switch (key) {
        case "number":
            // ERROR: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Mapping[K]'
            return 42; // Adding "as Mapping[K]" works, but that's not type-safe
        case "string":
            // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Mapping[K]'
            return "hello";
        default:
            throw "Never reached, but otherwise TS throws: Function lacks...";
    }
}

const usageWorksAsExpected = { n: get("number"), s: get("string") };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the support for [contextual narrowing of generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) added in TypeScript 4.3, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43183), doesn't do what you are expecting.  This support narrows the type of the `key` from `K` to either `"number"` or `"string"`, but it does not narrow the type of the type parameter `K` itself.  Even if `key` is confirmed to be `"number"`, the type parameter `K` is unchanged, and so the compiler cannot verify that `42` is assignable to `Mapping[K]`.  It's frustrating.

There are some open issues, like [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) which propose ways by which the compiler might narrow `K` itself.  But these have not been implemented yet.

If you'd like to rewrite `get()` so that it compiles with no errors and without giving up type safety, then you can do it like this:

```
function get<K extends keyof Mapping>(key: K): Mapping[K] {
    return {
        number: 42,
        string: "hello"
    }[key] // okay
}
```

Your return type is a generic [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Mapping[K]`.  The compiler *can* verify that if you index into a value of type `Mapping` with a key of type `K`, you'll get a value of type `Mapping[K]`, so that's why the above rewritten code works.

This relies on getting ahold of a value of type `Mapping`.  Sometimes you can't or don't want to do this because it forces you to eagerly pre-calculate the results for every possible input when you don't want to.  If so, you could implement [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead so that the `Mapping` object is lazily computed:

```
function get<K extends keyof Mapping>(key: K): Mapping[K] {
    return {
        get number() { return 42 },
        get string() { return "hello" }
    }[key]
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=69#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDMYCWA7AczgF44BvAKDmrjwFcBbAI2CgC5bGWoBuKmgM4wo+AhyEjCfAL58KAMzp4AxjBwQ8cAsBgAeANJxQMYHgAmAuAGtgiCPPRZchAHwAKG4g76AlB0zYogDa+gC65PzUUDp0UJqUNImczKwcACwATAA0kUkSohwARAAWwAA2ZRCFudJBnqEU0hQUyhpCcHQCGNoA6tBWAgCCAgCi4MCqwGYk5LQc2jBuhfQpUIU+WXAC8zpL+YTrcLLNiipqGlo6GQZGICbmlp72joGuHrbefi-OBCHhCTRojBYvFcokFsluG4fLMgSC4JkjjkkjQIfsCNDYTE4nASuVKoUjjU6rYGtIgA)

Answer (score 2):

Your code corresponds to [Suggestion for Dependent-Type-Like Functions: Conservative Narrowing of Generic Indexed Access Result Type #33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014)

The issue is not yet resolved, but one of the [comments suggests following workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014#issuecomment-570191837):

```
export type Mapping = {
    number: number;
    string: string;
};

function get<K extends keyof Mapping>(key: K): Mapping[K]
function get(key: keyof Mapping) : Mapping[keyof Mapping] {
    switch (key) {
        case "number": {
            const ret: Mapping[typeof key] = 42;
            const ret1: Mapping[typeof key] = 'hello'; // Expected error
            return ret;
        }
        case "string": {
            const ret: Mapping[typeof key] = 'hello';
            return ret;
        }
        default:
            throw "Never reached, but otherwise TS throws: Function lacks...";
    }
}

const usageWorksAsExpected = { n: get("number"), s: get("string") };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyBDMYCWA7AczgF44BvAKDmrjwFcBbAI2CgC5bGWoBuKmgM4wo%20AhyEjCfAL58KAMzp4AxjBwQ8cAsBgAeANJxQMYHgAmAuAGtgiCPPRZchAHwAKG4g76AlB0zYogDa%20gC6Ckqq6praMB62HJ72joGEPnD%20TsFJDgHOBKE0lDRwAgDuODDKABZw8YjpxSU0yhgCqABE9MysHRxNzc3KGkJwUDqZqQRBSCjJnoWkACwATHyDg8N4o%20MwAIyT%20TPIwPO2i3AA5NXAADa3EJc8cAD0L3AAouDAqsBmRlAoNB%20BsaLs6FBNLt1htpCChm1OhJRH1yPDQVsdhMUkdZqcHAsSFcbvdHjDQdRwZCxjpyc04aCzMB5Bg6LcYGx0RsYNUgWU4B0AHLAABurBpGBqfwANHAmHR4BAeawKu04AAVADKCF5EDKAg4ADFImoNHBbpKrAIAHS2jp0uFwiiY%20B0AQYbQAdWgVoAggIvihfv9SGRaBxYm4ulxej5ZQatDoo8jCB10rIKEA)